# TYPO3 I got an error by list after the installation of my own plugin

Tags: typo3

My TYPO3 version is 10.4.21 and I use extensions (Fluid styled content, sitepackage, Bootstrap, pizpalue and my own plugin which I made).

I created a plugin which names New Flipbox, because I have to make a new content element with a function of flipbox for my project work. But I have an error.

If I click a list button on the menu on the left side, an error occurred:

> Oops, an error occurred! An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT
> `uid` FROM `tx_myextensionkey_domain_model_newflipbox` WHERE
> (`tx_myextensionkey_domain_model_newflipbox`.`pid` = ?) AND
> ((`tx_myextensionkey_domain_model_newflipbox`.`deleted` = 0) AND
> ((`tx_myextensionkey_domain_model_newflipbox`.`t3ver_wsid` = 0) AND
> (`tx_myextensionkey_domain_model_newflipbox`.`t3ver_oid` = 0)))
> LIMIT 1' with params [1]: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not
> found: 1146 Table
> 'd037b84f.tx_rsnmizukiflipbox_domain_model_newflipbox' doesn't exist

How can I fix it?

For now, I've written down these:

in /typo3conf/ext/myextension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin(
   array(
       'My Flipbox',
       'rsnflipbox',
       'EXT:core/Resources/Public/Icons/T3Icons/content/content-carousel-image.svg'
   ),
   'CType',
   'myextensionkey'
);

 // Configure the default backend fields for the content element
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['flipbox_contentelement'] = [
    'showitem' => '
          --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
             --palette--;;general,
             header; Internal title (not displayed),
             bodytext;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:bodytext_formlabel,
          --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:access,
             --palette--;;hidden,
             --palette--;;access,
       ',
    'columnsOverrides' => [
       'bodytext' => [
          'config' => [
             'enableRichtext' => true,
             'richtextConfiguration' => 'default',
          ],
       ],
    ],
 ];
```

in /typo3conf/ext/myextension/ext_location.php

```
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig(
        'mod {
            wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.plugins {
                elements {
                    newflipbox {
                        iconIdentifier = content-dashboard
                        title = LLL:EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myextensionkey_newflipbox.name
                        description = LLL:EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myextensionkey_newflipbox.description
                        tt_content_defValues {
                            CType = list
                            list_type = key_newflipbox
                        }
                    }
                }
                show = *
            }
       }'
    );

    // wizards bei Plugin
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig(
        'mod {
            wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.interactive {
                elements {
                    newflipbox {
                        iconIdentifier = content-dashboard
                        title = LLL:EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myextensionkey_newflipbox.name
                        description = LLL:EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myextensionkey_newflipbox.description
                        tt_content_defValues {
                            CType = list
                            list_type = key_newflipbox
                        }
                    }
                }
                show = *
            }
       }'
    );

    $iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class);
    $iconRegistry->registerIcon(
        'myextensionkey-plugin-newflipbox',
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class,
        ['source' => 'EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Public/Icons/user_plugin_newflipbox.svg']
    );
});
```

in /typo3conf/ext/myextension/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript

```
lib.contentElement {
    templateRootPaths.200 = EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Templates/
}

lib.contentElement {
    partialRootPaths.200 = EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Partials/
}

lib.contentElement {
    layoutRootPaths.200 = EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Layouts/
}

tt_content {
    flipbox_contentelement =< lib.contentElement
    flipbox_contentelement {
        templateName = NewContentElement
    }
}
```

I saw a website of TYPO3(https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html) to create a element content, but I can't go on because of some errors.

What should I do now? I hope someone can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly states that the table `tx_rsnmizukiflipbox_domain_model_newflipbox` is missing. So you should check if you have added ext_tables.sql with the necessary database fields and then you should go to the install tool and do a database compare to create the missing table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll check it out then! Thank you.